# pkg_resource detect the wrong data_files path in virtualenv

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I use **data_files** in my `setup.py` for storing some files in my package.
And I also use `pkg_resources` module to get access to it. It works fine when I use install the package regularly. but when I install it via `virtualenv` the data files goes to the root directory of virtual environment. but the `pkg_resources` detects the `lib/python3.5/site-packages`.

P.S `sys.prefix` is root directory of virtualenv

why is that and how can I use `pkg_resources` correctly